# How to transform already transformed XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I currently have the following structure in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/" xml:space="preserve">
    <html>
        <head>
            <!--stuff here -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--stuff here -->
            <xsl:call-template name="page-content" />
            <!--stuff here -->
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The above file is being imported by other XSLT files, which implement the `page-content` template.  Here's a sample page-content template:

```
<xsl:template name="page-content">
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="row">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="data/document/content/node()" mode="copy" />
    </div>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to take the transformed XML returned by `page-content`, and match another template to it.  (The template is going to add another node to "main-container").  I am using XSLT 3.0

Is it possible for me to transform XML twice, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your description. In general, you can place the result of a transformation in a variable, instead of writing it to the output. Then apply another transformation to the contents of the variable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am new to the language, so my terminology is subpar, sorry.  If I understand what you are saying, I should surround the `<xsl:call-template>` with a `<xsl:variable>`, and then call `<xsl:apply-templates>` on that?  If so, could you provide an example of how to call apply-templates on a variable?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a [minimal, complete and verifiable sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the XML input, all XSLT stylesheets involved, and the output you expect.

Comment: I can provide a **simple** example - but you are complicating things by having multiple XSLT files. And you don't show us how exactly they are related to each other.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can deal with multiple XSLT files.  A simple example sounds fine to me.  I'm looking to learn concepts here, not looking for people to write code for me.

Comment: Can you give us a hint what the page-content template does (what does it process?). Also, which version of XSLT?

Comment: I am afraid I still don't get it. Is the named template really needed? FWIW, I have posted an example of two passes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple (and very artificial) example:

**XML**

```
<lines>
    <line id="1"/>
    <line id="2"/>
    <line id="3"/>
    <line id="4"/>
    <line id="5"/>
    <line id="6"/>
    <line id="7"/>
    <line id="8"/>
    <line id="9"/>
    <line id="10"/>
    <line id="11"/>
    <line id="12"/>
    <line id="13"/>
    <line id="14"/>
    <line id="15"/>
    <line id="16"/>
    <line id="17"/>
    <line id="18"/>
    <line id="19"/>
    <line id="20"/>
    <line id="21"/>
    <line id="22"/>
    <line id="23"/>
    <line id="24"/>
    <line id="25"/>
</lines>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/lines">
    <!-- first-pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="pages">
        <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
            <xsl:with-param name="lines" select="line"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pages"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="number">
            <xsl:number/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="line"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="paginate">
    <xsl:param name="lines"/>
    <xsl:param name="pagesize" select="10"/>
    <page>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$lines[position() le $pagesize]"/>
    </page>
    <xsl:if test="count($lines) gt $pagesize">
        <xsl:call-template name="paginate">
            <xsl:with-param name="lines" select="$lines[position() gt $pagesize]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <page number="1">
      <line id="1"/>
      <line id="2"/>
      <line id="3"/>
      <line id="4"/>
      <line id="5"/>
      <line id="6"/>
      <line id="7"/>
      <line id="8"/>
      <line id="9"/>
      <line id="10"/>
   </page>
   <page number="2">
      <line id="11"/>
      <line id="12"/>
      <line id="13"/>
      <line id="14"/>
      <line id="15"/>
      <line id="16"/>
      <line id="17"/>
      <line id="18"/>
      <line id="19"/>
      <line id="20"/>
   </page>
   <page number="3">
      <line id="21"/>
      <line id="22"/>
      <line id="23"/>
      <line id="24"/>
      <line id="25"/>
   </page>
</output>
```

The first pass divides the lines into groups of 10; then the second pass processes the groups.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking on the right lines: pipelines of simple transformations are the right way to implement a complex transformation, especially when it allows you to reuse the components of the pipeline. Because a stylesheet is essentially a function (the output is a function of the input), pipelining is equivalent to functional composition (applying one function to the result of another).

There are two ways of organizing a pipeline of transformations, "single-stylesheet" and "multiple-stylesheet". In the first case, as here, you capture the result of applying templates into a temporary tree held in a variable, and then you apply-templates to that variable, often in a different mode (to make sure that template rules apply only to one phase of processing). In the second case, you write separate stylesheets, and apply one to the output of another, using another language (Java, Ant, XProc, shell-script) to do the coordination.